# Django urls.py gives a 404 error while trying to access a URL

Tags: python, django, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create a Django app that uses these two urls, browse and account but I am getting an error when I try to access either of these two.

```
Using the URLconf defined in mediasite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^browse/
^admin/

The current URL, browse, didn't match any of these.
```

After looking over my code, I'm not sure where the error lies. The strange thing is the admin site still works.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^browse/', include('media.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

media/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from media.models import Video

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^videos', ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Video.objects.all().order_by("-created")[:2],
            template_name="media.html")),
    url(r'^videos/(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(
            model=Video,
            template_name="video.html")),
)
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'media',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like media.urls only has two urls, videos/ & videos/pk/

This means your only two url options are browse/videos/ and browse/videos/pk/

There is no url to just 'browse/'

If you wanted to add one, you'd need to add this to media.urls:

```
url(r'^$', some_view, name='some_view_name'),
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still fairly new to Django. Can't believe I missed that